# Throttling Tasks

Tags: c#, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

My service creates work in bursts and I would like to throttle the amount that happens concurrently. Assuming for simplicity that starvation of the work is not an issue, I am wondering if there is a difference from a perf perspective in simply leveraging the task scheduler + semaphore slim or doing this with a producer consumer.

For instance, what are the pros/cons of this general idea:

```
        var throttlingSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < hugeNumber; i++)
        {
            var arg = i;
            Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    await throttlingSemaphore.WaitAsync();
                    DoWork(arg);
                });
        }
```

And this:

```
           var workQueue = new AsyncQueue<int>();
            Task.Run(
                async () =>
                {
                    while (_isAlive)
                    {
                        int arg = await workQueue.DequeueAsync();
                        DoWork(arg);
                    }
                });

            for (int i = 0; i < hugeNumber; i++)
            {
                await workQueue.EnqueueAsync(i);
            }
```

Comment: You might want to look in to the [System.Threading.Tasks.DataFlow classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library), it is great for producer consumer setups and supports throttling concurrency.

Comment: What aspect are you trying to throttle? How much CPU gets used by this burst of work? How many tasks are outstanding at any one time? Also what synchronization context is in scope for these tasks (are they UI-bound? Thread pool-bound?). Keep in mind that the system can get a lot of work done with many pending tasks, since stuff like IO can be parallelized with very little CPU cost.

Comment: The work itself is not heavy, but it is less important than the rest of the system so we want to make sure only X happens concurrently.  It is thread-pool bound.  My main curiosity here is if there is a con in creating too many Tasks other than memory footprint.